# Grouping records time interval (start-end time) into groups of specific time interval (eg. 30 min)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I would like a query that would return the count of records that have their start-end time in specific time interval (eg. 30 mins).

For example records:

```
id|start|end
1|10:00|12:00
2|11:00|12:20
3|10:15|10:45
```

would result in

```
10:00-10:30|2x (records 1 and 3)
10:30-11:00|3x (all)
11:00-11:30|2x (records 1 and 2)
11:30-12:00|2x (records 1 and 2)
12:00-12:30|1x (record 2)
```

Usage: If I have for example 3 private instructors; I can't have more than 3 clients, meaning (in the example above) I can't appoint anybody from 10:30-11:00 as all 3 instructors are already occupied.

Comment: Welcome to our site!  Could you please show what you already achieved and where you are stuck?

Comment: *Always* declare your version of Postgres, and it's always helpful to disclose the exact table definition with (`CREATE TABLE` statement). Also, be precise. `in specific time interval` does not clarify how to handle lower and upper interval bounds exactly.